# Во время билда крашится проект React Native

Tags: android-studio, react-native

Я новичок в мобильной разработке и пытаюсь настроить React Native + Android Studio.  При этом у меня во время сборки проекта возникает такая ошибка:

> Configure project :app
>   WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (28.0.2) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.
>   2.1.
>   Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.3 will be used.
>   To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '28.0.2'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default vers
>   ion of the build tools.
>   Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 28 in C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\licenses
>   Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 28 not accepted.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

  > Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
  >    platforms;android-28 Android SDK Platform 28
  >   To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  >   Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

  Using Android SDK: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Command failed: gradlew.bat installDebug

Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat installDebug
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:637:11)
    at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:655:13)
    at runOnAllDevices (G:\react-native-gallery\Gallery\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\runAndroid\runAndroid.js:299:19)
    at buildAndRun (G:\react-native-gallery\Gallery\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\runAndroid\runAndroid.js:135:12)
    at isPackagerRunning.then.result (G:\react-native-gallery\Gallery\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\runAndroid\runAndroid.js:65:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:81:5)

[image: ошибки во время билда reac-native]
При этом, что лицензию я установил успешно. [image: установка лицензии]
Пытался гуглить ошибку, но никак не могу найти нужное кроме советов установить лицензию. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как устранить данную проблему. Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зайдите в cmd:

```
cd Users\{Name}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\tools\bin
```

или оно может находиться в другой папке:

```
cd Users\{Name}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin`
```

Потом запускаем команду:

```
sdkmanager --licenses`
```

Везде нажимаем 'y' и вуаля. Все работает.